# How to know that Process has crashed

Tags: c#, debugging, console

In my console application I have code which looks like

```
    Process DKU = new Process();
    DKU.StartInfo.FileName = "MSSQLExecutor.exe";
    DKU.Start();
    DKU.WaitForExit();
    Console.WriteLine("lets move on ");
```

This is working fine and it waits until MSSQLExecutor.exe finishes its job, then after that
the app continues.

My problem is that sometimes MSSQLExecutor.exe crashes and Windows by default shows a dialog for ending the program.  At that point my application will wait forever for the user to click the Close button.

I want to avoid this because MY application is going to run as a service without user interaction.

[image: After This I wanna to move on whit my app]

Comment: Is `MSSQLExecutor` your application? If so, I'd recommend *fixing the reason it crashes* instead of hiding the problem.

Comment: @DBM Unfortunately NO , SQLExecutor is not my app and I can't fix it.

Comment: Can you contact the vendor and tell them to fix their broken application, then?

Comment: Can you use something like [PTFB](http://www.ptfbpro.com/)?

Comment: @adopilot Then you can disable Dr. Watson. Check out my answer. We had the same problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Dialog prevents that the process exists.

1. **If `MSSQLExecutor` is your Application you should fix the problem. 
   But you can reach the goal (hiding the Dialog). Handle `Application.ThreadException` and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`**

   ```
   Application.ThreadException +=new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
   AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);


   static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
   {
       // log the exception
   }

   static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
   {
       // log the exception
   }
   ```
2. **If `MSSQLExecutor` is not your Application you can deactivate Dr. Watson**

   > Dr. Watson is an application debugger included with the Microsoft Windows operating system.

   - Click Start, click Run, type regedit.exe in the Open box, and then click OK.
   - Locate and then click the following registry key:
     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug
   - Click the AeDebug key, and then click Export Registry File on the Registry menu.
   - Delete the AeDebug key.

#### More Infromation

- [How to disable or enable Dr. Watson for Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188296/en-us)

Comment: Interesting. And if Dr. Watson isn't enabled, the process will die, as usual? And does that mean Process.WaitForExit() will stop blocking?

Comment: fyi I'm investigating if this'll solve a problem I'm encountering; it certainly looks like it. Additional info about Dr. Watson, including what looks like a safer way of disabling it than deleting the registry key: http://techdows.com/2009/03/how-to-fix-drwatson-postmortem-debugger.html    http://ccm.net/faq/6610-how-to-delete-disable-dr-watson-debugger

Comment: @dknaack should I put this code in `Program.cs` or each of my forms do it doesn't crash on clients' systems ?

Answer (score 6):

This is a frequent problem running outside processes.  From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298896/suppress-exception-popup-window-for-net-application-launched-from-unattended-co) I would suggest setting a maximum timeout value for this application.

```
Process DKU = new Process();
DKU.StartInfo.FileName = "MSSQLExecutor.exe";
DKU.Start();
DKU.WaitForExit(10*60*1000);

if (!DKU.HasExited)
        DKU.Kill();

Console.WriteLine("lets move on ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Relevent: [Detecting process crash in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309836/detecting-process-crash-in-net)

Also, you could call [Process.Kill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx) if you only wanted to wait so long for the process to finish.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to block waiting for the process to end, don't call Process.WaitForExit(). What's the goal of doing that? If you just need to know when it finishes, register for the Process.Exited event. In the Process.Exited event, you can check the Process.ExitCode to know whether it ended because of a crash or not.